# DateTime.ParseExact() Fails

Tags: c#, datetime

I am trying to parse a string using `ParseExact()` method:

```
DateTime.ParseExact(@"UTC 2014-07-08 13:11:40.396", @"UTC yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.FFF",null);
```

This gives following error message:

> DateTime.ParseExact(@"UTC 2014-07-08 13:11:40.396", @"UTC yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.FFF",null) threw an exception of type 'System.FormatException' base: {"String was not recognized as a valid DateTime."}

Comment: Try this code:
`DateTime.ParseExact(@"UTC 2014-07-08 13:11:40.396", @"'UTC 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.FFF",null);`

Comment: Depending on your server locale settings, you also need to pass the culture info (rather than `null`).

Comment: Works for me too, regardless of the culture

Comment: @coolerfarmer tried that.. still same result

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie I tried passing  System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture. Still same result

Comment: Is this the code that runs, or does your input come from variables? Check the variables.

Comment: Try `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture`. That will force it to ignore the culture settings (and is generally what I have had to use in production to avoid these problems).

Comment: @CodeCasterI copied that value from the variable and tried in immediate window

Comment: I can't get this to *not* work! Have tried various cultures. There's something missing here that you haven't told us.

Comment: @DavidG seems like some issue with culture settings. Anyway works fine with TrueBlueAussie's code

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture`. That will force it to *ignore the current culture settings* (and is generally what I have had to use in production to avoid these problems)

```
DateTime.ParseExact(@"UTC 2014-07-08 13:11:40.396", @"UTC yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.FFF",CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

From [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.invariantculture(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.invariantculture%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

> Unlike culture-sensitive data, which is subject to change by user
>   customization or by updates to the .NET Framework or the operating
>   system, invariant culture data is stable over time and across
>   installed cultures and cannot be customized by users. This makes the
>   invariant culture particularly useful for operations that require
>   culture-independent results, such as formatting and parsing operations
>   that persist formatted data, or sorting and ordering operations that
>   require that data be displayed in a fixed order regardless of culture.